# checkbox and Dropdown search in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox list, two dropdowns, two datepickers which are enclosed in a collapse panel.Below there is a gridview. The scenario is whenever a user selects any of the values and searches, the below values needs to be displayed in gridview.I have successfully implemented with the textboxes but having trouble with the dropdowns and checklist.Below is the code for your review.

```
StringBuilder filterExpression = new StringBuilder();
if (txtReferenceNumber.Text != string.Empty)
{
    filterExpression.Append("AND cac.AccountConsentID = "+ txtReferenceNumber.Text);
}
if (chkConsentStatusList.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    filterExpression.Append(" AND cacs.ConsentStatusTypeID IN (" + chkConsentStatusList.SelectedValue + ")");
}
if (ddlConsents.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
{
    filterExpression.Append(" AND c.ConsentTitleEN = '" + ddlConsents.SelectedValue + "'");
}
```

Comment: Is this MVC or WebForms? Include your 'view' code.

Comment: As I see with `Text` and `SelectedValue` property, OP has webforms page. Please include relevant ASPX markup for further analysis.